# How to make a C# method using PowerShell object constructed with runspace argument asynchronous

Tags: c#, powershell, asynchronous, async-await, using

Here is an example of some C# code opening a runspace from a remote connection, then invoking PowerShell.

```
        PSCollection<PSObject> Test(string remoteServerFullName, PSCredential mySuperSecretCredentials)
        {
            using Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory
                .CreateRunspace(new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri($"http://{remoteServerFullName}:5985/WSMAN")) { Credential = mySuperSecretCredentials, AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.NegotiateWithImplicitCredential });
            runspace.Open();
            using PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create(runspace);
            return powerShell
                .AddCommand("dir")
                .Invoke();
        }
```

I would like to make this asynchronous.

Options I've already tried:

1. Converting `runspace.Open()` to `runspace.OpenAsync()` throws the exception `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InvalidRunspaceStateException: The runspace state is not valid for this operation. ---> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InvalidRunspacePoolStateException: Cannot perform the operation because the runspace pool is not in the 'Opened' state. The current state is 'Opening'.`
2. Making the appropriate changes to the signature to make the method async and placing an `await` before `PowerShell.Create(runspace)` leads to build error CS1061: `PowerShell does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter`, etc.

Is there a way to properly ensure that the creation of the PowerShell object here waits for the runspace to be open before executing?

Answer (score 0):

The quick way is to wrap it with `Task.Run`:

```
PSCollection<PSObject> Test(string remoteServerFullName, PSCredential mySuperSecretCredentials)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory
                .CreateRunspace(new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri($"http://{remoteServerFullName}:5985/WSMAN")) { Credential = mySuperSecretCredentials, AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.NegotiateWithImplicitCredential });
            runspace.Open();
            using PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create(runspace);
            return powerShell
                .AddCommand("dir")
                .Invoke();
        });
}
```